# Javascript : How to display a variable in real time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to display each time when I put something in my input (like what I see in my console) :

```js
let inputNumber = 0;
    
handleInputChange(e) {
  inputNumber = e.target.value;
  console.log(inputNumber);
}
    
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
<h4>Data : {inputNumber}</h4>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: make that number stored in state, but it depends on which kind of component you use class component or functional component?

Comment: class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React and functional components, it would look something like this. You just need to store your input in a state and update the state when your input changes.

```js
function Component () {
    const [input, setInput] = useState(0);

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.valueAsNumber || e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.valueAsNumber || e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <input type="number" value={input} onChange={handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
        <h4>Data : {input}</h4>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use class component, store your inputNumber in `state`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { inputNumber: 0 };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputNumber: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={this.state.inputNumber}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
          pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"
        />
        <h4>Data: {this.state.inputNumber}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Code sandbox for demo

[image: Edit elastic-pine-2unh2]

Answer (score 0):

You need to track it into state by

```js
const [number, setNumber]=useState()
let inputNumber = 0;

handleInputChange(e) {
  inputNumber = e.target.value;
  setNumber(inputNumber);
}

<input type="number" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
<h4>Data : {number}</h4>
```